# select and highlight cells in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently doing something related to planning. So I have a table with time stamp. every row starts with a person's name. My idea is that first you can select one cell. Then you're blocked in that row and you can only select rows within that row unless no cells are selected.

Here's my code. Can someone help to realize it?

```
var isMouseDown = false, isHighlighted;
    $(document).on('mousedown','#werknemers_table tr td',function(){
        isMouseDown = true;
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
        console.log("Click");
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
        return false; // prevent text selection
    });
    $(document).on('mouseover','#werknemers_table tr td',function(){
        if (isMouseDown) {
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
                      isMouseDown = false;
                    });
```

Comment: What happens when you test this code?

Comment: Right now I can select any cells in the table. I want it in a way that if I select one cell and I can only select cells within that row but not any other rows, unless no cell is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the mouse down event happen add the 'current_row' class in its parent row. Then add highlighted class only the row having the 'current_row' class.

Use the below code:

```
        var isMouseDown = false, isHighlighted;
        $(document).on('mousedown','#werknemers_table tr td',function(){
            isMouseDown = true;
            console.log('mousedown');
               $(this).toggleClass("highlighted").closest('tr').toggleClass('current_row');

            console.log("Click");
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
            return false; // prevent text selection
        });
        $(document).on('mouseover','#werknemers_table tr td',function(){

            if (isMouseDown && $(this).closest('tr').hasClass('current_row')) {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
            }
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function () {
                          isMouseDown = false;
                        });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution I can think of, is to add another global indicating the current row.

```
var currentTR = null;
```

Then, set this in your mousedown event handler:

```
currentTR = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Then, your mouseover event:

```
if (!isMouseDown) return;
if (!$(this).parents().is(currentTR)) return;  // <-- ignore event if we're not a child of the relevant row
$(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
```

Another possible solution would be to set your mouseover event handler on just the relevant row in your mosedown event handler, and remove it again in your mouseup event.